# Iterate through shapefile and output an image for each feature using sf in R

Tags: r, features, color, loop, sf

I would like to create some statistical profiles for a range of features; specifically, 2016 Census profiles for the Census Divisions (CD) within British Columbia (BC), Canada. This would require a map showing each CD highlighted with respect to the other CDs (28 in total).

To do this using the [`sf` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sf/index.html) in [R](https://www.r-project.org/) and the [Statistics Canada Boundary files for 2016 Census Divisions (ZIP format)](http://www5.statcan.gc.ca/access_acces/alternative_alternatif.action?l=eng&dispext=zip&teng=lcd_000b16a_e.zip&k=%20%20%20%2032286&loc=http://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/2011/geo/bound-limit/files-fichiers/2016/lcd_000b16a_e.zip) [~32MB]
I would follow these pseudo-code steps:

1. Load the source `.shp`
2. Filter on BC (`PRUID = 59`)
3. Select the first feature/CD
4. Plot the entire set of features (black line with white fill)
5. Plot (with `add = TRUE`) the selected CD with some colour (black line with coloured fill)
6. Move to/select next feature/CD and go to Step 4

How would I code this in R?

The idea would be to generalize this so one can cycle through any set of features within a shapefile and output individual features highlighted within the entire geography.

Related: [How do I generate an image of each polygon in a shapefile?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/159472/8160)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The steps to perform this task using [`sf`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sf/index.html) would be:

```
library('sf') # Load sf package
library('dplyr') # Load dplyr package
# Load 2016 Census shape file for Canada (Step 1)
can_cd_2016 <- st_read('lcd_000b16a_e.shp')
# Filter on British Columbia/BC (PRUID == 59) (Step 2)
bc_cd_2016 <- can_cd_2016 %>% filter(PRUID == '59')

# Set general plot parameters (if needed):
# MARgins to 0 lines c(bottom, left, top, right)
# Line WiDth to 0.1
par(mar = c(0,0,0,0), lwd = 0.1)

# Loop through each CD (Steps 3 and 6)
for (CD in 1:(nrow(bc_cd_2016))) {
  # Open PNG stream to 'bc_cd_2016_CD#.png'
  png(paste('bc_cd_2016_', bc_cd_2016$CDUID[CD], '.png', sep = ''))
  plot(bc_cd_2016)# Plot BC (Step 4)
  plot(bc_cd_2016[CD,], col = 'red', add = TRUE)# Plot CD/feature (Step 5)
  dev.off()# Close PNG stream
}
```

The output is a set of files with title `bc_cd_2016_#.png` where `#` denotes the `CDUID`. Example of `bc_cd_2016_5947.png`:

[image]

...or when cycling through `bc_cd_2016_59??.png` (using [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php)'s `convert` to GIF):

[image]